# Wrong number of arguments for a filter

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use this hook:

```
$actions = apply_filters( "wc_memberships_for_teams_teams_area_{$section}_actions", $default_actions, $team, $object );
```

where $section is "members".

I'm doing it like this:

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_for_teams_teams_area_members_actions',    'add_guideline_action' , 10, 2, 4 );
     function add_guideline_action( $actions, $team, $member ) {
            $actions = array_merge( array( 'guidelines' => array(
                'url'  => "/thingy",
                'name' => __( 'Guidelines', 'woocommerce-memberships-for-teams' ),
            ) ), $actions );
        return $actions;
    }
```

But im getting the error

```
Too few arguments to function add_guideline_action(), 2 passed in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 312 and exactly 3 expected in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child/functions.php:332
```

Why? isnt the hook giving three?  $actions, $team and $object.

Comment: Because you have this `add_filter(.... 'add_guideline_action' , 10, 2, 4 );` There are two many arguments there. You only need `add_filter( 'wc_memberships_for_teams_teams_area_members_actions',    'add_guideline_action' , 10, 3 );` filters and hooks pass three things: callback, priority, and argument count. `2` and `4` are causing your error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: its not a typo, i dont know enough about how to call the hook!

Comment: I'm calling it a typo - because WP documentation is pretty clear and there's not really a better close reason to pick from. I realize you didn't know :) But this question/answer is not likely to help future visitors. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct code is:

```
add_filter( 'wc_memberships_for_teams_teams_area_members_actions',    'add_guideline_action' , 10, 3 );
 function add_guideline_action( $actions, $team, $member ) {
        $actions = array_merge( array( 'guidelines' => array(
            'url'  => "/thingy",
            'name' => __( 'Guidelines', 'woocommerce-memberships-for-teams' ),
        ) ), $actions );
    return $actions;
}
```

the arguments are: filters and hooks pass three things: callback, priority, and argument count.

Thanks to @disinfor for the answer in the comments.

The argument count defaults to one.

Ref:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/